# Why do USB-C cables stop working one one device, but still work on other?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-c, charging, phone

This might be a bit weird question. I have a phone (Samsung Note 20) and other USB-C devices (headphones, tablet, microphone, etc...). When a cable is first used for charging my phone it works fine (for some time, lets say 1-5 months). After that it starts having issues, either charging very slow (5h+ for full charge) or does not charge at all (no cable indication on phone). That same cable works fine with other USB-C devices.

Right now I have 5 different USB-C cables, from cheap ones, expensive ones and a JBL speaker charging cable (speaker charges with no issues). All of them have either stopped working, or it is really hard to get them to work with my phone. I have to reinsert and/or flip them around many times for the phone to start charging - IF it even starts. Also, all of them work fine with other devices.

When I use a new or borrowed USB-C cable, phone recognizes the cable immediately and starts charging. Charging port on phone does not look dirty/stuffed with debre.

Anyone have any idea why that would happen? I understand that the cable can get damaged, but why would it still work on other devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, as USB cables have evolved, different pins have been used for the higher power capacity to avoid damaging earlier equipment.  So, the same cable may work on one device but not on another.

Samsung is particularly strict in its fast charging modes.  Even though the USB-C connector is supposed to be reversible, I find that on many cables (with Samsung), one orientation works for fast charging, while the other does not.  I mark the plugs on these cables.

If a cable has been damaged, then it's possible that some wires are damaged but not all.  Meaning it will work for some devices and not others.

Finally, the power sources/chargers also have this issue with pins

Reference of [Pinouts](https://www.wellpcb.com/usb-pinout.html)

Here is another take on it.

> The sources of USB‑C charging damage
> The pin pitch of USB‑C connectors is 0.5 mm ― much tighter than the 2.5-mm pin pitch in USB Type-A connectors. This tighter pitch significantly increases the risk of a fault that could cause a thermal event. When connector pins become deformed or dust, metal particles, hair, or other debris gets stuck in a USB‑C cable connector, a resistive fault can be created from the power line to ground. These resistive faults can cause a dangerous temperature rise while increasing current only minimally.

Reference [The big problem with fast charging using USB Type-C cables](https://www.electronicproducts.com/the-big-problem-with-fast-charging-using-usb-type-c-cables/)